# c++ call function every 5 minutes

Tags: c++, while-loop

I wanted to call function every 5 minutes
I tried

```
AutoFunction(){
    cout << "Auto Notice" << endl;
    Sleep(60000*5);
}

while(1){

    if(current->tm_hour == StartHour && current->tm_min == StartMinut && current->tm_sec == StartSec){
        CallStart();
    }

    AutoFunction();
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

I want refresh the `while` every 1 second  and at the same time `call AutoFunction()`; every 5 minutes, but without waiting the `Sleep` in AutoFunction

because I have to refresh the while(1) every 1 sec to check time to start another function

I thought to do it like

```
while(1){

    if(current->tm_hour == StartHour && current->tm_min == StartMinut && current->tm_sec == StartSec){
        CallStart();
    }

    Sleep(1000);
}
while(1){

    AutoFunction();
    Sleep(60000*5);
}
```

but I don't think so both will working together

Thank You

Comment: Sounds like a good time to use threading. Thread A loops forever, calling `AutoFunction` and sleeping for five minutes. Simultaneously, thread B loops forever, calling `CallStart` when appropriate and sleeping for a second.

Comment: Looks like a perfect use case for one of [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html1)'s timers.


  [1]:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those of us who are unfamiliar with threads and Boost libraries, this can be done with a single while loop:

```
void AutoFunction(){
    cout << "Auto Notice" << endl;
}

//desired number of seconds between calls to AutoFunction
int time_between_AutoFunction_calls = 5*60;

int time_of_last_AutoFunction_call = curTime() - time_between_AutoFunction_calls;

while(1){
    if (should_call_CallStart){
        CallStart();
    }

    //has enough time elapsed that we should call AutoFunction?
    if (curTime() - time_of_last_AutoFunction_call >= time_between_AutoFunction_calls){
        time_of_last_AutoFunction_call = curTime();
        AutoFunction();
    }
    Sleep(1000);
}
```

in this code, `curTime` is a function I made up that returns the Unix Timestamp as an int. Substitute in whatever is appropriate from your time library of choice.